# ctypes how to pass string from python to c++ function, and how to return string from c++ function to python

Tags: c++, python, string, ctypes

I want to call a c++ function from python, this c++ function takes char* as parameter, and return string. Below is my code.

wrapper.cpp

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C"
string return_string(char* name){
    cout<<strlen(name)<<endl;
    cout<<name<<endl;
    string s = "hello ";
    s += name;
    return s;
}
```

compile wrapper.cpp to example.so

```
g++ -fPIC wrapper.cpp -o example.so -shared -I/usr/include/python2.7/
```

wrapper.py

```
import os
from ctypes import *

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./example.so')
lib.return_string.restype = c_char_p
lib.return_string.argtypes = [c_char_p]
name = create_string_buffer("Tom")
s = lib.return_string(name);
print s
print name
```

here is my output

```
18
��H�L�l���A���
1
<ctypes.c_char_Array_4 object at 0x7f5f480be710>
```

How to make it works?

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem, but your C++ code is invalid, before you even get to Python and ctypes. An `extern "C"` function can't return a `string`. After a quick test, it looks like that probably _is_ the problem, so I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has nothing to do with ctypes; your C++ code is invalid in itself. You can't define an `extern "C"` function that returns a `string`.

In a quick test with a C++ program that uses the same library, it also prints garbage.

I also wrote a C program that defines something called `string` with the same layout as `std::string` just so I could compile it and see what happens; it also prints garbage, and then it segfaults in `~string`.

So, it's not surprising that the Python program also prints garbage.

With a minor change, everything works:

```
extern "C"
const char *return_string(char* name){
    cout<<strlen(name)<<endl;
    cout<<name<<endl;
    static string s = "hello ";
    s += name;
    return s.c_str();
}
```

I get this output:

```
3
Tom
hello Tom
<ctypes.c_char_Array_4 object at 0x11011c7a0>
```

(Or, from the C++ version, the same thing but with "Tom" in the last line.)

Of course for obvious reasons this isn't a very good solution, but it shows that returning `string` is the problem.

Both g++-4.5 and clang-apple-4.0 warned me about exactly this problem when I tried to compile your C++ code (although g++-apple-4.2 didn't, unless I added an extra -W flag). When the compiler gives you a warning, that's often the answer to "why does my code do the wrong thing even though it compiles".

A few other things wrong with your code:

- You don't make any use of anything from Python in your .cpp file. And in general, the whole point of using `ctypes` is so your C or C++ code doesn't have to know anything about Python; it's your Python code that knows about it. So, don't include or link.
- It's generally a bad idea to take a non-const `char*` if you aren't planning to modify it. My C++ driver had to call it with `const_cast<char*>(name.c_str())` instead of just `name.c_str()`. Also, this can prevent the compiler from noticing other things that you're doing.

Here's the C++ driver I mentioned above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

extern "C" string return_string(char* name);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  string name("Tom");
  string s(return_string(const_cast<char *>(name.c_str())));
  cout << s << "\n";
  cout << name << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Also, if I play around with different optimization settings or reorganize the code a bit, in my C++ driver, sometimes your code actually works, sometimes it prints garbage, and sometimes it segfaults. My first guess would be that it depends where the `~string` call gets inlined—but really, the details don't matter; the code shouldn't work, and it doesn't, so who cares why?

Comment: That `return_string()` is returning the result of calling `c_str()` on something that then goes out of scope and will get deconstructed. Isn't that problematic? Not that I see a way around it.

Comment: No it isn't. In my version, `s` has static storage class, not automatic. If you don't know what that means, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable for some background, but the short version is that its lifetime isn't tied to its scope; it lives for the entire lifetime of the process. That's why it works, and that's also why it's not a very good real-life solution.

Comment: Oh whoops, missed the `static`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, especially 'A few other things wrong with your code'