# C++ function in python return number instead of string

Tags: python, c++

C++ that creates string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

extern "C" {
    string getchars() {
        string output = "";
        char letters[4] = { 'A', 'G', 'T', 'C' };
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            output += letters[rand() % 4];
        }
        return output.c_str();
    }

}
```

Python code that should return string generated in C++:

```
from ctypes import cdll
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('mylib.so')
print(lib.getchars())
```

And it returns different numbers like 18806352, What should I do to return normal string? In C++ This functions works well

Comment: `string getchars` should be `char *getchars`, since that's what `c_str()` returns.

Comment: @Barmar That would return a pointer to a local .

Comment: The string returned by `c_str()` becomes invalid when the `std::string` is destroyed. Since `output` is destroyed when the function returns, you can't return `output.c_str()`.

Comment: I think you need allocate a dynamic C string and copy `output.c_str()` to it, then return that pointer.

Comment: @Barmar I have no idea how to do it, I'd be grateful if you write a bit of code how could I do it and why

Comment: `return strdup(output.c_str());`

Comment: Did you try `return Py_BuildValue("s", output.c_str())` ?  That returns a python object of type string and it should appear as a string in python.

Comment: @Barmar `'strdup' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: @DNT `Py_BuildValue' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: @WhoAmI `#include "<Python.h>"` and add the libs to your linker. Ref. https://docs.python.org/3.0/extending/extending.html

Comment: @DNT That's Python 2.7 documentation, you should probably update your links.

Comment: @Barmar Trivialities :) There you go.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ctypes how to pass string from python to c++ function, and how to return string from c++ function to python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500069/ctypes-how-to-pass-string-from-python-to-c-function-and-how-to-return-string)

Comment: @WhoAmI Whenever you see that error `....not declared in this scope` it means you are missing a header and if the function is not part of the standard C++ libraries, you also need to add the library to your linker. For python, you do need to write your extension as the python documentation indicates to avoid headaches, refcount issues and memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this discussion. This issue seems a lot similar with
[How to return char ** from C++ and fill it in a list in Python using ctypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709994/how-to-return-char-from-c-and-fill-it-in-a-list-in-python-using-ctypes)

It appears you need to specify the return type of the fuction in cdll.
So you need to define the result type before calling the method.

I think this should work. Otherwise have a closer look to:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html

[EDITED]

- C++ implementation of file `test.cpp` (implementation of @Barmar):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

extern "C" char * getchars() {
    string output = "";
    char letters[4] = { 'A', 'G', 'T', 'C' };
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        output += letters[rand() % 4];
    }
    char *return_string = new char[output.length() + 1];
    strcpy(return_string, output.c_str());
    return return_string;
}
```

- Compilation:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -fPIC test.cpp -o test.o
g++ -shared test.o -o test.so
```

- Python file `test.py`:

```
from ctypes import cdll, c_char_p
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./test.so')
lib.getchars.restype = c_char_p
result = lib.getchars()
print(result)
```

Python version 3.7.4

This should work.

Comment: now my `lib.getchars()` (after print(...)) prints me `<__main__.LP_c_char_p object at 0x00FD2760>`, how can I get the value?

Comment: Try using lib.getchars().value

Comment: `lib.getchars().value` and `lib.getchars().values` doesnt work

Comment: As this is a python object it has a type and a value.

Comment: Be aware that you might need to allocate the data via a malloc or something. Because otherwise even if you return .c_str() at the end, the string object is already destroyed. So you need to allocate this data to give it to python and free it in python.

Comment: I actually have no idea how to realize it -.- Would be greatful if you'd tip me how to do it if you know

Comment: Thanks a lot! What have you done that it started to work? Tell please as an edit and I will accept your answer!

Comment: Basically, the things that you did wrong are to not allocate the memory on the C++ side. The ```char * return_string = new ... ``` allocates memory which is not freed. Keep in mind that when we are exiting the method, the destructor of output will be invoked.
Then on the python side, I specified the actual result type c_char_p which means the method returns a char *. And I made sure the path to the library is correct. i.e. "./test.so", because before it was not finding the library.

Comment: Everything else, it is more or less the same, you don't need the cast ```result = lib.getchars()```, as you might have discovered.
Keep in mind C++ destroys all the memory that you allocated (RAII). So in case that you are doing this type of bridges you need to allocate a memory that is not freed and which is common to both C++ and Python.
The reset is just implemenation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a C string, not a C++ `std::string`. You'll need to make a dynamic copy of the `c_str()` so it will have lifetime past the function that created it.

```
extern "C" {
    char * getchars() {
        string output = "";
        char letters[4] = { 'A', 'G', 'T', 'C' };
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            output += letters[rand() % 4];
        }
        char *return_string = new char[output.length() + 1];
        strcpy(return_string, output.c_str());
        return return_string;
    }
}
```

Comment: `'strdup' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: It's two lines of trivial code to emulate, I added it to the answer.

Comment: did what you've wrote, included `#include <string.h> #include <stdlib.h>`, .so object created, but in python returns number anyway.. Did you tried it yourself? Maybe it will make some sence in the case it work for you or I missed sth

Comment: @WhoAmI i suppose python still prints the value of the pointer instead of the string

Comment: I assumed that ctypes would do the appropriate conversion to Python string.